# Can't change className within an onclick function JS

Tags: javascript, scope, classname

Doing this tutorial, however when I run on inspector debugger, content.className always remains ="" it only is open for the set transition period for the assigned .onclick function. So the effects of the function only lasts temporarily.

````
var button= document.getElementById("show-more");

button.onclick = () =>{
    //of the content has a class name of open then we open the box
    if(content.className== "open"){
        //if it's already opened then we shrink the box
        //revert to normal
        content.className= "";
        button.innerHTML= "Show More";
    }else{
        //else we expand the box
        //if it's closed we add open as it's class
        content.className= "open";
        button.innerHTML = "Show Less";

    }
}```
````

Comment: Why don't you post a runnable code using code snippet feature in StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0):

try `content.classList.add("open");` to add 
and `content.classList.remove("open");` to remove

Comment: so what was wrong with what I did? does it have anything to do with the scope?

Comment: I tried and it ended up with the same result ```var content = document.getElementById("content");
var button= document.getElementById("show-more");
button.onclick = () =>{
    if(content.className== "open"){
        //if it's already opened then we shrink the box
        //revert to normal
        content.classList.remove("open");
        button.innerHTML= "Show More";
    }else{
        button.innerHTML = "Show Less";
        content.classList.add("open");
    }
}```